# Why I can't access the endpoint I've set up on my @RestController

Tags: java, spring, maven

I've recently started learning Spring and wanted to exercise a bit.
I've created a simple spring boot application, so far it contains only 1 controller with single @GetMapping, but when I try to test it in my browser I only get Whitelabel error. Could someone hint me in the right direction?

Controller:

```
package com.calculate.calories.web.controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

@RestController
public class RecipeController {

    @GetMapping("/recipe")
    public String getRecipes() {
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("https://api.aniagotuje.pl/client/posts/search?categories=ciasta-i-torty&diets=&occasions=&tags=&page=0&sort=publish,desc"))
                .GET()
                .timeout(Duration.of(10, ChronoUnit.SECONDS))
                .build();

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newBuilder().connectTimeout(Duration.of(15, ChronoUnit.SECONDS)).build();
        try {
            HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
            return response.body();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "e";
    }
}
```

Main:

```
package com.calculate.calories.start;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SlimChefApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SlimChefApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Main POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <modules>
        <module>config</module>
        <module>persistence</module>
        <module>common</module>
        <module>application</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.calculate.calories</groupId>
    <artifactId>slimchef</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SlimChef</name>
    <description>SlimChef</description>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <project.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
    </properties>


</project>
```

POM of application module (where controller is):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>slimchef</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.calculate.calories</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>application</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

POM of config module (start point of Spring application):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>slimchef</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.calculate.calories</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>config</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.calculate.calories</groupId>
            <artifactId>application</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.calculate.calories</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK44Y.png)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You either use `spring-boot-starter-web` or `spring-boot-starter-webflux` but not both. If you need both you need to specify to the application what it needs to run SERVLET or REACTIVE (or NONE but I doubt that applies). Add `spring.main.web-application-type=SERVLET` if you want to use servlet (blocking) or `REACTIVE` otherwise).

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for hint, yeah that was a case and as well the fact that I forgot to add package scan for the module containing controller....
You should add your comment as answear otherwise I can't mark it as solution.

Thank you for your imput, any advice how I should approach learning Spring or what materials to go through? (except documentation ofc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see 2 things "wrong" with your setup

1. You have both `spring-boot-starter-web` and `spring-boot-starter-webflux in your dependencies. You generally use 1 or the other not both.

To fix remove one of the dependencies and decide what you want, or specify what Spring should start. For this you can use the `spring.main.web-application-type` in your properties and set it to either `SERVLET` or `REACTIVE`.

2. Your `@SpringBootApplication` is in the `com.calculate.calories.start` and it will, by default, scan only in the package it is defined in (and its subpackages). Your controller is in `com.calculate.calories.web.controller` which doesn't match.

The best practice is to put your `@SpringBootApplication` in a top level package, in your case `com.calculate.calories`. If you don't you endup with a class with a lot of additional `@ComponentScan`/`@IMport`/`@Enable*` annotations, which kind of beats the purpose of auto configuration and detection.

So in short move your `@SpringBootApplication` class to `com.calculate.calories` instead of a sub-package.